# How to enter text into RichEditor text box using puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer

I want to enter text in this text box with Puppeteer. I was using this xpath //div[@class='ui input custom-input-form content--translatable-variable-name:-field'] but this does not work.

```
const title = await page.$x("//div[@class='ui input custom-input-form content--translatable-variable-name:-field']");
await title[0].type("Test");

<div class="RichEditor-editor content--translatable-question-text:-field"><div class="DraftEditor-root"><div class="DraftEditor-editorContainer"><div aria-describedby="placeholder-3d1bl" class="notranslate public-DraftEditor-content" contenteditable="true" role="textbox" spellcheck="false" style="outline: none; user-select: text; white-space: pre-wrap; overflow-wrap: break-word;"><div data-contents="true"><div class="" data-block="true" data-editor="3d1bl" data-offset-key="e9fsv-0-0"><div data-offset-key="e9fsv-0-0" class="public-DraftStyleDefault-block public-DraftStyleDefault-ltr"><span data-offset-key="e9fsv-0-0"><br data-text="true"></span></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>
```

Comment: Does it work in DevTools console?

Comment: No, it does not work